# Leaking MainActivity through WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have an app whose Activity has a fragment with a webView. This webView is being instantiated with an Activity context, as the documentation indicates.

The problem lies when, with the "Don't Keep Activities" flag is turned on, we navigate to another activity and back. This Activity is re-instantiated, but looking at the heap dump I saw a memory leak bind to this Activity.

Looking at the [reference trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F23Cs.png), `OnscreenContentProvider` is referenced, a class that is used in [WebView class](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/glue/java/src/com/android/webview/chromium/WebViewChromium.java#1827).

This class in turn uses [ClassLoaderContextWrapperFactory](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:components/embedder_support/android/java/src/org/chromium/components/embedder_support/application/ClassLoaderContextWrapperFactory.java;l=27;drc=da3bb54157d4603b9c820d6cfdf61859f804dfb2;bpv=1;bpt=1?q=ClassLoaderContextWrapperFactory&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc) which contains two static references to a context.

Which seems to indicate that there is a bug and is leaking the context. Has anyone an idea what might be going on or even reproduce it?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and what helped me was to add:

```
webView.removeAllViews();
webView.destroy();
```

to `Activity.onDestroy()`. I think, its important to call `webView.removeAllViews` before `webView.destroy()`.

Comment: This does get rid of the leaks, but it really seems like a Chromium bug.

Comment: I had this issue both in native android and in embeded flutter inappwebview plugin for WebView. Acutally inappwebview plugin has lots of kind of tricks to safely destroy webview - together with loading empty page in which onPageFinished is executed code for removeAllViews and destroy. Yet it still leaked, the solution for flutter leak was to prolong the time ShowDialog was beeing closed - I think the onPageFinished required more time to finish.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @M.Muzammil have you identified where your leak originates from? I always use for it android studio memory profiler: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler . LeakCanary - also works well